# How to clear the left bit of the n-th bit position

Tags: c

i have a problem, i have to learn for the next week exam and i have the following exercise

**Set the bit position to *n* and clears the bit to the left of that position. For a=0x20 and *n=5* it should be 0x10 and for a=0xFB and *n=2* it should be 0xF7.**

I tried the *n+1* considering the 6th bit is in the left of the 5th, but it doesn`t work, thank you in advance.

```
int main() {

   unsigned char a = 0x20;
   unsigned char b;
   unsigned char c;

   int n = 5;
    // setting the bit to n position
    b = a | (1 << n);
    
    //clearing the left bit of n position
    c = b & ~(1<<(n+1));

    printf("The result is: 0x%x\n", c);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The examples don't agree. The first sets bit 4 (N-1) and clears bit 5 (N), while the second sets bit 2 (N) and clears bit 3 (N+1).

Comment: Yes, you are right, that s why i was so confused getting the correct answer for the second one but not for the first, so is it correct the method i applied to clear the left bit of N position right?

Answer (score 0):

The example is inconsistent, but assuming `n` is a bit index (goes from 0 to length-1):

```
unsigned solve(unsigned a, unsigned n)
{
    unsigned result = 0;
    
    unsigned pmask = 1U<<n;
    unsigned nmask = ~(pmask<<1);
    
    result = a|pmask;
    result = result&nmask;
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Given that `1<<31` has undefined behavior, it would be safer to use `1U << n` and use `unsigned` instead of `int` everywhere.

Comment: @chqrlie I agree with your first comment, but why `nmask = ~((pmask << 1) - 1);`?